# How to create sign up form(ModelForm) using meta class as django.contrib.auth.models.User?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a sign up form and create a User(model).

I am very new to django and I cannot figure out how to do so.
I have written this but this doesn't seem to work well.

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def is_valid(self):
        if super(SignUpForm, self).is_valid() and  self.confirm_password == self.instance.password:
             return True
        else:
            False

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if self.is_valid():
            self.instance.objects.create_user(username=self.instance.email, email=self.instance.email,
                                          password=self.instance.password, first_name=self.instance.first_name,
                                          last_name=self.instance.last_name).save()
```

When I try to access `confirm_password` it throws AttributeError 
`AttributeError: 'SignUpForm' object has no attribute 'confirm_password'`

And more-over when I am trying to accesss the other attributes of the meta class like `password` , `email`, `first_name` and `last_name` using `self.instance` attribute it always returns a null string `''`. Can anyone please tell me the correct and an efficient method to create a sign up model form. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the built-in User model, the easiest way to do this is to use the built-in [UserCreationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm). You can import this from `django.contrib.auth.forms`. Bonus, it's got a "confirm password" field built in.

Comment: Reusing the user creation form, rather than writing your own is a good idea. Depending on your requirements, you might find the [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.3/) app useful.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't override the `is_valid()` method, override `clean` instead. In the `clean` method, you can fetch the values from `self.cleaned_data`, e.g. `self.cleaned_data['password']`. See the [docs on validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [chapter of tango with django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/login.html) although it was for Django 1.7 ,still you will get the idea.
And don't forget to go through the django documentation , if you want to understand it completely.

Cheers!
Happy Coding!